# What is a large scale website?

Tags: terminology, definition

I was reading a job listing that said:

> MUST have prior experience on large
>   scale websites

What is the definition of a large scale website? Is it defined by a certain number of pages in a site or traffic perhaps?

What is a large scale website as referred to in the job listing?

*** EDIT ***

This is the full job listing so you can see how it relates to the position:

**Strong HTML Developer**

Specific Requirements:

- MUST be local and be able to work onsite.
- MUST have prior experience on large scale websites
- Prior ad agency/comparable experience is ideal
- Possible Fulltime Opportunity

Comment: This answer to this is liable to be subjective or broad. I'd recommend posting this question on programmers.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: That being said, I think for your particular case you should really use your own subjective sense of it (do *you* feel like you've worked on a large-scale website?) or a guess at what the author of the job listing meant. Without seeing the original listing you are referring to, it's hard to gauge this.

Comment: Ben, please see the edited portion. I added the full listing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A movable feast.

I would personally measure the size of a site by a combination of it's traffic, it's server footprint, and (where applicable) it's sheer content, but the statement here is obviously unqualified so you're guessing at what large is. Biggest thing I've worked on had two "pages" but had several thousand requests per second, which is more important?

If I was hiring I would basically consider any non-trivial site (i.e. more than a four page site for some random shop or hotel or such) sufficient, but not meaningful in and of itself.

Answer (score 3):

Large scale website is a relative phrase, for what one consideres large, another considers mid-sized.

I would expect they want somone who has worked with the issues of high visitor volume and spreading a website over multiple machines - maybe even over an entire server farm.

I would also expect that a large scale website has *a lot of* individual pages or sections.

Definitly large scale websited are the portals of intel.com or microsoft.com, both in sheer volume of information presented and dayly visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Definitions of large scale can differ.

But even if we don't know exactly how to measure scale and just *how large* is large, I think we can say that if a site runs on only *one box* it's probably *not* large scale.